# How to transfer an image via REST API? (Core 2.0 inside)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create an Authentication App with ASP.NET Core 2.0, and I'm trying to create some REST methods. What I want to do is to create a GET method that returns the Profile Image. I got this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UserProfileController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetPicture(string username)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

        return Ok(user.Picture);
    }
}
```

And it actually works. The fact is that calling this method return the base64 string representation of my image. But what I want is to get the Image itself. Then, I tried to change the `GetPicture` method to this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetPicture(string username)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(user.Picture);
        Image image;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        return Ok(image);
    }
```

But it doesn't work as I hoped. I supposed it is a problem of Content-type, so I tried to change the `[Produces("application/json")` to `[Produces("image/jpeg")` or something similar. But it doesn't work, since it gives me back a *406 Error: Not Acceptable*. I'm running out of ideas, so I'm asking you if you can help me out with this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that to return a file you can simply `File(user.Picture, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image returned, then simply return the bytes with the appropriate mimetype. Returning an `OkResult` is going to cause whatever object you pass in to be serialized and the whole response sent as `application/json`, which obviously is not an image. This is all you need:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPicture(string username)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(user.Picture);
    return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: As you said, that's what I needed. Thank you!